# CSS: triangle above an dialogue box disappears on setting overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a dialogue box or a arrow box which should be set to max height of 60%, and all the content inside the box overflows via scroll, this is the markup:

```
<div class="cart">
    hello world
</div>
```

and here is the css to make a arrow-head on top:

```
.cart {
    position: fixed;
    background: #ffffff;
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 74.8%;
    width: 300px;
    top: 70px;
    padding: 13px;
    z-index: 20;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    max-height: 60%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.cart:after, .cart:before {
    top: -20px;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;

}

.cart:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
.cart:before {
    border-color: rgba(12, 143, 176, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #999;
    border-width: 11px;
    margin-left: -11px;
}
```

if I remove the "overflow" property the arrow head shows up, but when I use it, which I have to It disappears, I want both, an arrow head and scrollable div, but I think the arrowhead just gets inside the scroll. is there any solution for this?

Thanks for the help

Comment: yes use another element to style the triangle which is outside of this container.

Comment: I dont know how, I just copied the code from a website

Comment: try https://jsfiddle.net/n01ajfff/